# Why is this "where" clause not limiting sql results

Tags: mysql, sql, select, operator-precedence

I'm trying to limit results in a table to records with dates that don't overlap my data. As you can see in the screenshot below I'm trying to add a clause to filter out records that are equal to the "end" column. See the final line in the query for that.

I can't figure out why results still show the record in the screenshot. Can someone help me out explaining that? It's probably a syntax thing?

[image: SQL Where clause not filtering]

Comment: Tip: you're using parenthesis in the only place where they aren't helpful.

Comment: code as an image isnt really useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically have:

```
a OR b AND c AND d AND e AND f
```

... and you probably want:

```
(a OR b) AND c AND d AND e AND f
```

Reference: [Operator Precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operator-precedence.html)

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Makes total sense!

Answer (score 2):

`AND` has a higher [operator precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) than `OR` has.

That means that your `AND` clauses will be interpreted first so that at the end there's something like

```
where (...) or (... and ... and ...)
```

Since the first condition before the `OR` (`('2014-01-14 18:30:00' between start and end)`) is met, your row shows up. Put both sides of the `OR` clause in parantheses and it should work as you want to.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the first part of your `WHERE` clause is passing that record. I believe you need to more your brackets around a bit.

I'm not completely sure on what you are trying to achieve with the data that you have provided, but an opening bracket after the `OR` keyword and a closing bracket right at the end should do it.

Like this:

```
where
('2014-01-14 18:30:00' between start and end)
or (('2014-01-14 19:30:00' between start and end)
and ('2014-01-14 18:30:00' != start)
and ('2014-01-14 19:30:00' != end)
and ('2014-01-14 19:30:00' != start)
and ('2014-01-14 18:30:00' != end))
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `2014-01-14 18:30` is between `2014-01-14 16:00` and `2014-01-14 18:30` which is a **TRUE** condition. And [(TRUE) Or (whatever else)] is also **TRUE**